# CakePHP containable how to do a recursion with join?

Tags: cakephp, recursion, cakephp-model, containable

I want to retrieve tree nodes recursively and want to join each [Node] with [Level]
Node:

```
 ...
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Parent' => array(
        'className' => 'Node',
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_id'
    ),
    'Level' => array(
        'className' => 'Level',
        'foreignKey' => 'level_id'
    )
);
 ...
```

Controller:

```
$this->Node->contain(array(
        'Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent',
    ));
$parentTree = $this->Node->findAllById($id);
```

the recursion works already but I want each Node to have a Level element and now it's not the case.
How would be the correct contain parameter?
Levels are recursive as well but in this case a want to restrict the recursion - need only the first one

Comment: You don't want to use recursive at all.  Set it to `-1` in your AppModel and thank me later.

Comment: a bit more explaination?

Comment: I would explain more, but I really don't understand your question.  You mention recursion, but don't show what it's set to.  Then you have a very strange contain and you don't show what results you're hoping for.

Comment: I have a tree of nodes which can be 6 levels deep and I want to fetch all the precessors

Comment: Are you using the built in Tree behavior?